# Netbeans 11.3 doesn't mark as an error the use of a nonexistent class

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 11.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.4. I've run into a strange issue that becomes visible after doing the following steps:

Create a new Maven Project (New Project -> Java with Maven -> Java Application) - I use user.xmpl as my package name.

Create two classes in that project, with the following code:

FirstClass.java:

```
package user.xmpl;

public class FirstClass {
    public FirstClass() {
        object.function(() -> {});
        }
}
```

SecondClass.java:

```
package user.xmpl;

public class SecondClass {
    FirstClass testClass;
    BadClass badVariable;
}
```

There is no error message on the BadClass badVariable line, nor on any other line in the SecondClass file (BadClass is not defined). The file as a whole is marked as having an error, in the tab and in the Project tree.

The error *is* shown (as expected) with any of the following changes:

- Switch the order of the two definitions within SecondClass
- Delete the first definition (FirstClass) in SecondClass
- Delete the constructor of FirstClass
- Delete the one line in FirstClass (object.function)
- Remove the lambda expression from the line in FirstClass
- Use a Java Ant project instead of a Maven one

There is, of course, an error on the object.function line, but there is no change in the issue if that error is fixed by appropriately defining object and function. I removed any extraneous code to help isolate the issue.

Does anyone have any idea why no errors show up on the BadClass badVariable line? Is this a bug in Netbeans, and if so how should I report it? Can anyone confirm that this happens on their system?

Comment: If you do end up thinking it's a bug, go to Help > Report Issue from the IDE's main menu. This takes you to the [issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-3858?filter=allopenissues). Check if the issue has already been reported.